# Multiplying elements in custom lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to implement a custom multiplication operation for my custom list data type in Haskell that uses an `Int` and `[Int]`.
`Int` is used to reduce integers by modulus division I will refer to as `d`.
`[Int]` represents the content of the list

Let's say `a` and `b` are two lists that have the same `d`.
The length of `a` is `w` and the length of `b` is `v`

The `c = a*b` is:

```
c[k] = a[0] * b[k] + a[1] * b[k - 1] + a[2] * b[k - 2] + · · · + a[k] * b[0]
```

At the end, `c[k]` is reduced by `mod d`.
The length of `c = w + v - 1`

Meaning the index `k` in `c[k]` can be larger than the lengths of `w` and `v`.
To deal with this I concatenate a list of 0 elements for indices outside the bounds of the original list.

To clarify:

```
c[0] = (a[0] * b[0]) % d  
c[1] = (a[0] * b[1] + a[1] * b[0]) % d  
c[2] = (a[0] * b[2] + a[1] * b[1] + a[2] * b[0]) % d  
.  
.  
.  
c[w + v - 1]
```

For example, `a = [3,2,4]` and `b = [7,9,7,2]`, both have `d = 31`.

In the code when they are being multiplied they are `[3,2,4,0,0,0]` and `[7,9,7,2,0,0]`

In this example, `c = a * b = [21, 10, 5, 25, 1, 8]`

This is my code:

```
module Custom where

    data CustomList = CustomList Int [Int]
    instance Num CustomList where
        (CustomList a1 b1) * (CustomList a2 b2) = 
            if length b1 >= 1 && length b2 >= 1  then do 
                let llen = (length b1) + (length b2) - 1

                --concatenating a list of 0 elements for indices outside the bounds of the original list. 
                let sub_b1 = llen - (length b1)
                let sub_b2 = llen - (length b2)
                let zeros_b1 = map (0*) [1..sub_b1]
                let zeros_b2 = map (0*) [1..sub_b2]

                --matching list lengths
                let new_b1 = b1++zeros_b1
                let new_b2 = b2++zeros_b2

                --trying to mimic a nested for loop
                let ans = [ (new_b1 !! x) * (new_b2 !! y) | x <- [0..llen-1], y <- (reverse [0..x]) ]

                CustomList (a1) (map (`mod` (a1)) ans)
            else do
                0

    instance Show CustomList where
        show (CustomList a b) = "output: " ++ (show b) ++ "\nlength: " ++ (show a)
```

Output:

```
*Custom> let a = CustomList 31 [3,2,4]  
*Custom> let b = CustomList 31 [7,9,7,2]
```

Incorrect (What I get)

```
*Custom> a * b  
output: [21,18,14,28,5,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  
length: 31
```

Correct (What I should get)

```
output: [21, 10, 5, 25, 1, 8]  
length: 6
```

I realize issues in my logic:

1. The `x` counter, I need to start from `a[0]` and end at `a[k]` for all `c[k]` calculations but I am starting at `a[x]`.
2. Answers are not being summed together. For instance, instead of obtaining `c[1] = a[0] * b[1] + a[1] * b[0]`, I obtain `c[1] = a[0] * b[1]` & `c[2] = a[1] * b[0]`

I am not sure how to fix it, I have been trying and end up just creating new problems by trying to do.

I am a newbie at Haskell so I would prefer a simple readable way of solving this problem over the more "Haskell" way of doing it.
But any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice and simple:

```
data CustomList = CustomList Int [Int] deriving(Show)

instance Num CustomList where
  CustomList a1 b1 * CustomList a2 b2 = CustomList a1 (map (`mod` a1) ans)
    where ans = map getAnsElem [1..length b1 + length b2 - 1]
          getAnsElem k = sum $ zipWith (*) (withLength k b1) (reverse $ withLength k b2)
          withLength n xs = take n (xs ++ repeat 0)
```

Testing it:

```
λ> CustomList 31 [3,2,4] * CustomList 31 [7,9,7,2]
CustomList 31 [21,10,5,25,1,8]
```

Explanation:

- `withLength` takes a list and makes it a given length, either by truncating it if it's too long, or padding with zeros if it's too short
- `zipWith` takes 2 lists and goes over them in parallel, using the given function to combine the elements
- One reason your approach with a list comprehension failed is because `[f x y | x <- xs, y <- ys]` takes the Cartesian product of `xs` and `ys` instead of zipping them. If you wanted to use a list comprehension instead, you could, but you'd need the `ParallelListComp` extension, in which case you'd have this:

```
getAnsElem k = sum [x * y | x <- withLength k b1 | y <- reverse $ withLength k b2]
```

Note the second `|` instead of a `,`: this is what denotes zipping.